# Unity3d share image on android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, share, classcastexception

Trying to implement android image sharing on a Unity game, I've put together several sources, this is my current code.-

```
public static void shareImage(string subject, string title, string message, string imagePath) {
    #if UNITY_ANDROID

    AndroidJavaClass intentClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Intent");
    AndroidJavaObject intentObject = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent");
    intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setAction", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_SEND"));
    intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setType", "image/png");
    intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_SUBJECT"), subject);
    intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_TITLE"), title);
    intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_TEXT"), message);

    AndroidJavaClass uriClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.net.Uri");
    AndroidJavaClass fileClass = new AndroidJavaClass("java.io.File");

    AndroidJavaObject uriObject = uriClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("parse", "file://" + imagePath);

    intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_STREAM"), uriObject);

    AndroidJavaClass unity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unity.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    currentActivity.Call("startActivity", intentObject);

    #endif
}
```

it looks ok to me, and `share with...` dialog gets opened, but the image isn't appearing, and I'm seeing an error on android console.-

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.net.Uri$StringUri cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
    at android.os.Bundle.getParcelableArrayList(Bundle.java:805)
    at android.content.Intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.java:5823)
    at com.whatsapp.ContactPicker.b(ContactPicker.java:93)
    at com.whatsapp.ContactPicker.onCreate(ContactPicker.java:551)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6500)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3072)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3218)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:198)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1676)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

I'm guessing that android is expecting `EXTRA_STREAM` to be an `ArrayList`, but as far as I know this is only true when using `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`. May I be missing something obvious here?

Comment: Your code looks OK. Can you please expand stacktrace? On what line of your code the exception occurs?

Comment: Thanks @naXa, just updated my question; the unity code is working fine, the exception is being thrown by android once I click share and choose the application I want to share with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share Image on Android Application from Unity Game](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36512784/share-image-on-android-application-from-unity-game)

Comment: Thanks @Programmer, I think the general code is pretty similar, but that question doesn't talk about mh issue, any idea why is the exception being thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the issue had nothing to do with the exception, external apps just had no visibility for attached files as I was saving them on internal app storage.

Enabling `WriteAccess->External (SDCard)` on Unity `Player settings` solved the issue.