# Share Image from Memory to Android Unity Game

Tags: java, unity-game-engine, java-native-interface, share, screenshot

This question is related to this previously answered question [Share Image on Android Application from Unity Game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36512784/share-image-on-android-application-from-unity-game)

My question is this:

Is there a way to share the image WITHOUT using a file?  I'd like to remove the sd card read/write permission on Android.  I'm not a Java programmer, so I'm having a heck of a time getting it working.  None of my attempts have yielded anything.

"Programmer" answered the previous question with the below code, which works great for me.  I basically want to use the variable imageBytes instead of the file.  Is this even possible?

```
void takeScreenShotAndShare()
{
    StartCoroutine(takeScreenshotAndSave());
}

private IEnumerator takeScreenshotAndSave()
{
    string path = "";
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    Texture2D screenImage = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height);

    //Get Image from screen
    screenImage.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), 0, 0);
    screenImage.Apply();

    //Convert to png
    byte[] imageBytes = screenImage.EncodeToPNG();


    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.persistentDataPath + "/GameOverScreenShot");
    path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/GameOverScreenShot" + "/DiedScreenShot.png";
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, imageBytes);

    StartCoroutine(shareScreenshot(path));
}

private IEnumerator shareScreenshot(string destination)
{
    string ShareSubject = "Picture Share";
    string shareLink = "Test Link" + "\nhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/36512784/share-image-on-android-application-from-unity-game";
    string textToShare = "Text To share";

    Debug.Log(destination);


    if (!Application.isEditor)
    {

        AndroidJavaClass intentClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Intent");
        AndroidJavaObject intentObject = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent");
        intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setAction", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_SEND"));
        AndroidJavaClass uriClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.net.Uri");
        AndroidJavaObject uriObject = uriClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("parse", "file://" + destination);

        intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_STREAM"), uriObject);
        intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_TEXT"), textToShare + shareLink);
        intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_SUBJECT"), ShareSubject);
        intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setType", "image/png");
        AndroidJavaClass unity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unity.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        currentActivity.Call("startActivity", intentObject);
    }
    yield return null;
}
```

[Unity3d share image on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39321128/unity3d-share-image-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly pass the **byte array**, no need to convert it to file -> uri  -> string

Below are java code, but you can easily translate this to JNI wrapper calls

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putByteArray("byteArr", imageBytes); //put byte array to bundle!!!
Intent intent = new Intent(...);
intent.putExtra(bundle );
```

To retrieve the image byte array in another activity, use below code:

```
getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArr");
```

If you wrap each above function calls into a corresponding JNI function, it would be very tedious. You can on the other hand:

- Create an android library project
- Add two static java functions, one is saveByteArrayToBundle(...), and the other is getByteArrayFromBundle(...)
- Compile the android library into an aar file;
- then put the aar file into the Assets/ folder (actually any subfolders will do)
- Then call the two static java functions as you have done in the OP

Refer to below tutorials if you need to go through step-by-step:

- [Step-by-Step guide for developing Android Plugin for Unity3D (I)](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2015/12/31/step-by-step-guide-for-developing-android-plugin-for-unity3d-i/)
- [Step-by-Step guide for developing Android Plugin for Unity3D (II)](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2016/08/10/step-by-step-guide-for-developing-android-plugin-for-unity3d-ii/)

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick answer, but I don't know Java so I won't be able to easily translate this.  I'll give it my best and reply back.

Comment: you don't need know java, you just translate it  with your own code as reference.

Comment: Giving this a shot:

Comment: I'm getting an AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.net.Bundle.  I believe that's the class I need to use correct?  Maybe this is just not available in Unity?

Comment: @JasonHowerslitz See my updated answer and tutorial links therein. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, that'll help a lot.  Once I get it working I will mark as answered!